# Delete Azure Virtual Machine automatically after instance-initiated shutdown

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2

In Amazon Web Services, I am currently using the built-in feature to automatically terminate (delete) a virtual machine after the instance itself has initiated a shutdown. See the link below for more information on this option.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior

I am working on a similar setup in Microsoft Azure but I struggle to find the same feature. I have successfully configured both the disk and the network interface to be deleted with the virtual machine (rather than being detached) but I still cannot find the option to delete the entire virtual machine after my program running on the machine has initiated a shutdown. Does this feature not exist in Azure?

Comment: There is no such features available in azure to delete resources directly, but we can delete using terraform or PowerShell script using runbook.